# Can't import QtGui from PyQt4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I downloaded PyQt4 , sadly when i try to import PyGui it replies with the following error :

```
  >>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtGui'
```

so i tried to use different methods to import the module :

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtGui import *

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
ImportError: No module named 'sip'
```

After that i tried to install "sip" module , results are :

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for sip

**Note** : My python version is 3.5

***Update***:**I Uninstalled Python3.5.1 and replaced it with Python3.4** , yet there's no results.

```
 >>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

***update2***: I tried to copy Qtcore4.dll and QtGui.dll to main dictionary but no Results.

Comment: uninstall 3.5, install 3.4

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I had to set this up, but I believe the python Qt bindings require some of the DLL's included in the VC2015 C++ redistributable:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

If installing that one doesn't work for you, grab Process Monitor/Process explorer and watch for the DLL's it tries to load, and see which one it fails on.